# How can I make this YouTube link work on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, youtube, html5-video, shadowbox

I am using Shadowbox.js for showing YouTube videos.

However, on iOS devices, when I click to play the video, it returns a message regarding my browser not recognizing any of the supported formats available. I assume this is because it is flash.

My link looks like [this](http://youtube.com/embed/4gfupvPFZPg)

I assumed YouTube would forward me to a HTML5 version of the video, but it does not.

Any idea how I can format this link to play on iOS?

I thought the issue was directly with Shadowbox, but it displays this error even if I paste it into mobile Safari.

Many thanks,
Michael.

PS - I have even tried appending `?html5=1` to the end of the URL but still no joy.

Answer (score 1):

Not all videos are encoded as HTML5 on Youtube, so it may just be that there isn't an HTML5 version. You shouldn't really have to do anything to make it work.

Comment: I thought that too, but I have tried several videos that work through the iPhone YouTube app...but when I navigate to an equivalent EMBED URL, they do not work. So there must be a .h264 version there.

Comment: Remember that the Youtube App won't exist in a few weeks! (Not that it's of relevance!) I've just tested your code with some other videos, and all worked, so it is the case that your video doesn't have an h264 version that's working there for some reason… In short, there isn't anything you can do as far as I know, except hope that it starts working! Are there adverts on the video?

Comment: Do you have an example video that you know to work on iOS? How is it possible to get a .h264 video? I assumed YouTube would do automatic conversion. These videos will not have ads. Yes the app will be gone - but it's not relevant, I'm just saying that to show that there must be a version that works on iOS on YouTube's website. In other words, how could I force a HTML5 player / video with an embed URL?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/embed/sPQhxXlQVj8 works for instance. Youtube will do automatic conversion, but perhaps there is some lag before they will do it? As you already know, adding ?html5=1 should work, but only if they have the video for use. It seems that they just won't serve an h264 version of that video for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm afraid your example video does not work on my iPhone 4S. For example, this is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/4HSzG.png can you confirm that you see the same or not? I just need it to work on iOS and now I'm pulling my hair out over something that should be seemingly simple. Hmm. Thanks for your input so far, would appreciate your further thoughts.

Comment: ...interestingly, when the link is placed within an iFrame it will work. I think I'm not understanding something here.

Comment: That's not what I see, for me it works fine. However, I'm on iOS6. Can you link to your web page that has the shadowbox etc that doens't work?